# Pattern Recognition Algorithm/Technique

Tags: algorithm, iteration

### Background

I apologize for the music-based question, but the details don't really mean all that much. I'm sequentially going through a midi file and I'm looking for an efficient way to find a pattern in the data to find something called a tuplet. See image below:

[image]

The tuplets have the numbers (3 or 6) over top of them. I need to know at which position they begin in the data file. The numbers below the notes are the values you would see sequentially in the data file. Just in case you can't decipher the data below, here it is:

1, 2, 2.3333, 2.6666, 3, 3.5, 3.6666, 3.83333, 4, 4.1666, 4.3333, 4.5, 4.6666, 4.8333,
5, 6.3333, 6.6666, 7.1666, 7.3333, 7.5, 7.6666, 7.8333, 8, 8.1666, 8.333, 8.5, 8.6666.

- The first tuplet begins at position 2 and the difference between the position of notes is 0.3333 (repeating)
- The second tuplet begins at position 3.5 and the difference between the position of notes is 0.1666 (repeating)

The main issue is that in the note, unlike the image below, position 7 will not be noted in the data file because the data only file only lists note locations. The icon that you see in that location is called a rest, which is not notated in the data file.

### Question

How can I find an efficient method to find the start of each tuplet? Is there some sort of recursive method?

Comment: Doesn't the MIDI file include the duration of the note (which combined with the start of the note would allow detecting the rest)?

Comment: It does include the duration of the notes, but unlike notes in notation where things are a fixed length, midi note length are not always predicable. Therefore, it's tough to know exactly how long a rest may be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need any recursion for this.

The normal note values can only be represented by fractions of the beat of the type `a / 2^b`. The tuplets can be arbitrary fractions, but mostly I've seen something like triplets, quintuplets or (in your case sextuplets).

So the simplest way would be to compute the length of every note (maybe the time difference between two MIDI events? Or the length is stored explicitly in MIDI? I'm not that familiar with the format) and compute the rational representation of this length.

Every group of notes with a denominator that is not a power of two belongs to such a tuplet. To group the notes together, I would recommend the following approach (assuming that all notes of a tuplet have the same value):

- Factorize the denominator into a power of two `a` and the rest `b` (e.g. `a * b = 4 * 5`)
- Initialize an empty tuplet of size `b`
- For every note compute the distance to the beginning of the tuplet and store the note at the corresponding position, inserting rests if necessary. The length of the tuplet can be computed by taking the minimum length `l` of all notes in the tuplet, so greedily adding them until the end of these notes exceeds a distance of `l * b` from the beginning of the tuplet
  This way, you base the tuplet on the minimum note length and add all notes that fit into it.

Comment: This doesn't entirely work: tuplets don't have to be of equal length.  For instance, you can have a triplet tied across an "eighth" and "quarter", rather than three "eighth" notes.  Otherwise, it's a reasonable starting point, needing only adjustment for the rests (which can also be tied into tuplets).

Comment: I fixed the answer in this regard, though i'm not sure if this is the best way to compute the note length the tuplet is based on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @TobiasRibizel. My app is currently ONLY reading position, not duration. I keep the duration of the notes the same because this is a drumming app, so the length doesn't matter. It seems that you and Prune are on the same wavelength, but I'm a little lost by your notation. Can you provide an example of what a and b represent based on the positions I posted? Sorry for being so slow.

Comment: Actually I'm using *a* and *b* in two different ways. If you mean the first example: You can write 2,333... = 7/3, since 3 is not a power of two, it belongs to a tuplet. If you mean the second example: 7,1666... = 43/6, decomposing 6 into 2 * 3 = a * b tells you that you have a triplet (b = 3) I'm guessing you're okay with a sextuplet being represented by two triplets, otherwise it gets a bit more complex.

Comment: Oh okay. I get it. Yes, I'm definitely okay with the sextuplet as two triplets. I understand that 2.3333 is 7/3, but where does the 7 come from? Do you have some sort of running count for something else going on? Also, at the beginning of your response you had mentioned duration, does this work in terms of position because that's really what I need.

Comment: If you assume that your notes don't overlap, you can identify tuplets by notes that are not aligned at power-of-two values. Note that this identifies the second/third/... note of a tuplet, but the first one is usually aligned at a beat. The 7 comes from the representation of 2.3333 as a rational number.